# C - Append to my array?

Tags: c, arrays

Real quick question, probably the time why I've forgotten such a basic thing!

I am capitalizing the first letter in an array, and I then want to append a 1 (to begin with onto the end) - I am generating word lists for WPA/2 networks as part of my Network Security research.

So, work out the length of the word, then, in the position in the array at the end of that word, place a number 1, or 2 ,or 3.

Totally forgotten how you do it though!

```
void capFirst(char *s, int i) {
s[0] = (toupper(s[0]));
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int i;
char fileSave[256];
char myString[50];
FILE *fpIn, *fpOut;
for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    fpIn = fopen(argv[i], "rb");
    snprintf(fileSave, 256, "%s~[%d]", argv[i], i);
    fpOut= fopen(fileSave, "wb");
    while((fgets(myString, 49, fpIn)) != NULL) {
        if(isspace(myString[0]))
            break;
        i = strlen(myString);
        if( (i > 8) && (i < 64) ) {
            capFirst(myString, i);
            fprintf(fpOut, "%s", myString);
        }
    }

    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Something like, s[strlen(s) + 1] = 'x' ?

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: you are still not making any sense.  1, 2 or 3?  Are your words limited in length to 3 characters?

Comment: As in, I have an array containing hello, and I want to modify it, so that it becomes  Hello1

Comment: There are no dynamically resized arrays in C.  Memory management of the array is "hands on".  Apparently you are treating a string as an array of char's in passing the argument to `capFirst`.  This is feasible as far as just capitalizing the first character is writing over previously allocated memory for that given string.  But if you want to "make the string longer", the paradigm breaks down.  You'd have to allocate room for the longer string, copy the required characters there, and then replace old references (pointers) to the string with the new pointer.  Not much fun, huh?

Comment: Do you mean if input file has "Abcdefg\n hello", you want output to have "Abcdefg1\n Hello2"?

Answer (score 2):

You would need

```
i = strlen(string);
string[i] = whatever you want there;
string[i+1] = 0;
```

But you have to ascertain that `string` has enough space for the 0-terminator.

By the way, you use `i` as the loop counter in the `for` loop as well as for the `strlen` inside that loop, that's generally a bad idea.

Comment: Hmm, it adds it to the front of the word :S

Comment: Huh? If `strlen` works correctly, its result is the position of the 0-terminator, the end of the string. So the above places the new character at the end.